# Logic app read property of json stored in variable

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have this json in a Logic App variable. I want to 'id' property of this JSON and use further. How to get this id property value?

My json is:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "John bright",
"username": "Lily",
"email": "abc@aabc.com",
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You said your json is a variable, but you don't mention which type it's stored.

1. Stored as string. In this way the whole json is a string, it's not supported to select property. So you need parse it to Json with `Parse JSON` action then you will be able to select property. About the `Parse JSON` Schema, just click the `Use sample payload to generate schema` and paste your json value, it will generate. And select your property just use the `@{body('Parse_JSON')?['name']}`, it will work.

[image]

[image]

2. If it's stored as an Object, it will be easier to do it, just use expression `variables('test1')['name']` to get it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @dotnetavalanche, does this work? If this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Parse Json action and use your payload as a "Use sample payload to generate schema". After that, id will be listed as a Dynamic content from the Parse Json action.